# SSH authentication failed bitbucket server

Tags: ssh, bitbucket-server

I am trying to connect to bitbucket server via ssh. And i get `Host key verification failed`.

I sued this guide https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/ and added my public key to the server and every thing seems to be setup correctly.

I ran `ssh -v  git@bitbucket.corp.jyskebank.net` and get this. Is there a way to fix it?

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.corp.jyskebank.net [10.16.207.13] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.corp.jyskebank.net:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/pe/xQGds7FWBp5Oj1710EfF8g9EL+Uo+kVfqy3IEQA
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.corp.jyskebank.net' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/JB4555/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/JB4555/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: "And i get Host key verification failed" That's not what the debug output shows. Which ssh key is it supposed to use to connect to github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there was no error. But the problem was that vscode cannot connect via ssh, when the key contains a passprahase